# How to render video frames in chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc

I've setup a http server in my Android phone. I'm getting the frames from the camera of my android phone in the form of ByteBuffer[] array.
Is there a way to decode and render the video in chrome (probably using webrtc or something).
PS. I'm a noob with video and stuffs.

Comment: What are the frames encoded as? Jpeg? WebM(Vp8)? Or something else? You should just be able to send them to a video html5 tag depending on  the networking situation.

Comment: They're encoded as mp4 I suppose.

Comment: There may be issues playing mp4 videos in chrome...